# MS SQL sub query from all tables does not work

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv, sql-server-2019

I tried to make a subquery from all tables I have in the MS SQL database. Separately both queries work fine, but when add as a subquery it gives the error.

PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT CustomerNumber, M3, DARICXVA, MONTH_X FROM (SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '%DATA_20%') WHERE CustomerNumber = 752376952";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if( $stmt === false)
{
   echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";  
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  //this loop is working
{ 
  echo $row['CustomerNumber'].", ".$row['M3'].", ".$row['DARICXVA'].", ".$row['MONTH_X']."<br>"; 
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Would you like to tell us exactly what the error is? Or do we get extra points for guessing!?

Comment: P.S. It would really make sense to test this directly in SQL (e.g. via SSMS) and get it working, before integrating this into the PHP. Have you tested the query by itself?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: It doesn't work that way! `... FROM (SELECT ...)` will select from result of inner select, not from tables which names are in inner select.

Comment: You can't execute a Dynamic SQL query as if it were a normal query.  While you can use parameters for WHERE clauses, you can't simply parameterise the FROM.

You have two options.  Call sp_executesql to execute the Dymamic SQL string, or run one query to get the table name, then put that in a PHP variable and construct the SQL Statement in another PHP variable before executing it.

Comment: `SELECT table_name from` returns one column. You can't then select a load of different columns from the result of that. They don't exist! e.g. `CustomerNumber, M3, DARICXVA, MONTH_X`...none of those exist in `SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables`. Only a column called `table_name` is available. And clearly those other columns don't exist anywhere in the information schema anyway.

Comment: I understand what you say guyz, what might be solution any ideas? @planetmatt Thanks for your good answer...

Comment: P.S. If your design includes multiple tables with the same column in them, then you almost certainly have a data normalisation problem. You need to fix your schema design instead of trying to implement bizarre workarounds such as this. I strongly smell a [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Almost certainly, all this data should be in _one_ table, possibly with an extra column to categorise it, rather than separated into multiple different tables.

Comment: `what might be solution `...well planetmatt outlined one. But my last comment may turn out to point to the real, long-term answer. There might be exceptions to that rule, but it's not clear if any of them would apply here, as we don't quite know enough about the scenario.

Comment: My solution would be to put the whole DB call into a MSSQL SPROC and just execute that. Hide all the Dynamic SQL inside that SPROC and just use the PHP to pass the variables into SPROC parameters and read the resulting recordset.   

To do that, the only gap in your knowledge is how to use sp_executesql  and you can google that easily.

Comment: @planetmatt agree, this might be great solution, but i can not, database is not on my side and they have tables separately. I will do as you advised. I tried to do simple way :))

Comment: Can you not ask them to deploy the SPROC for you for you to execute?  Embedding SQL queries into code makes it impossible for DBAs to tune if code that runs fine against a handful of test records turns out not to scale in a few months time once deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do dynamic SQL like this. You need to build a dynamic string of code and execute it using `sp_executesql`.

```sql
$sql = "
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  CustomerNumber,
  M3,
  DARICXVA,
  MONTH_X
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
WHERE CustomerNumber = 752376952'
  AS nvarchar(max)), '
' )

FROM sys.tables t
WHERE t.name LIKE '%DATA_20%';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
";
```

Note that `sp_executesql` accepts parameters, you should use that if you have any to pass in, such as `@CustomerNumber = 752376952`.